# matlab write equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have *data in `x` and `y`*, and I want to solve *the next equation using Matlab*. How can I write  matlab CODE equation ?

```
y= y1, ...,y(n-1),yn;
x=x1,...x(n-1),xn
```

for example

```
C= 0.2345+5.423*y(n-1)*x(n-3)+2*y(n-5)*x(n-4)
```

Comment: Hi, the question is not clear. I'm sure we can help you if you can make the question clearer and show what you have tried so far in MATLAB.

Comment: I think you just did. What is the problem?

Comment: @umTaha : did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you are describing is a vector/matrix multiplication problem, which you can code as:

```
c0 = 0.2345; % this is your first constant that you use in C

n = 6;       % for the sake of argument, I will assume n=6;

M = [ 0      2      0      0      0      0;
      0      0      0      0      0      0;
      0      0      0      0      0      0;
      0      0      0      0      0      0;
      0      0      5.423  0      0      0;
      0      0      0      0      0      0];

C = c0 + y' * M * x;
```

I was assuming that both vectors, `x` and `y` are column vectors. Matlab notation says that `y'` is the transpose of vector `y`, which is a row vector.

When we write `C = c0 + y'*M*x`, then we essentially say that (using pseudo-code)

```
C = c0 + sum(i=1:n)( sum(j=1:n)( m(i,j) * y(i) * x(j) ) )
```

Please note that this approach allows you to store *any* factor multiplying `y(i)*x(j)` simply in position `M(i,j)`.